# How do you convert latin1 to utf8 character encoding?

Tags: php

So, I currently have this problem - I have a sql db dump and the character encoding in it is latin1, but there are some utf8 chars in the file that look like Ä (should be ā) Ä« (should be ī) Å¡ (should be š) Ä“ (should be ē) etc. How do I convert these leters back to the original utf8.?

Character in the file <-> what it should have been <-> bytes

Ä“ <-> ē <-> 5

Ä  <-> ā <-> 2

Å¡ <-> š <-> 4

Ä« <-> ī <-> 4

Comment: What tool are you looking to use to re-import the file?

Comment: I'm importing it to my database with phpmyadmin. After it is imported I change the encoding from latin1 to utf8

Comment: How exactly do you "change the encoding"? Is this before or after you have the problem?

Comment: To change the encoding I simply open up my phpmyadmin, go to the structure view of the table, edit the row and change the encoding in there by selecting the utf8 collation.

Comment: Collation doesn't change encoding, only the connection encoding will adjust that.

Comment: Don't show us the character as a character - tell us the Unicode value you were expecting. Likewise, don't show us *how many* bytes are used to represent it - tell us what those bytes are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're seeing multiple bytes for what should be single characters, chances are it's already *in* UTF-8. Bear in mind that ISO-8859-1 is a single-byte-per-character encoding, whereas UTF-8 can take multiple bytes - and any non-ASCII character *does* take multiple bytes.

I suggest you open the file in a UTF-8-aware text editor, and check it there.

Comment: I tried opening it in Notepad++ and set the encoding to "UTF-8 without BOM", but it didn't work

Comment: @Matiss: What exactly do you mean by "it didn't work"? And did you set the encoding *while loading it*? It's not always clear whether setting the encoding when you've already loaded the file reloads the file in the new encoding or *changes* the file to the new encoding version of what it *thought* it was before. Have you looked at the file in a hex editor? If you could post a couple of failing characters in terms of the expected Unicode character number, and the bytes representing it in the file, that would help.

Comment: @Matiss I'm fairly sure your problem will go away the moment you actually import the file back into the database. Is that part of the process not working? What tool are you using to import the file?

Comment: @Jon By that I mean that the characters didn't change back to the ones they should have been in the 1st place. Ä - should have been ā - 4 bytes. Ä£ - should have been ģ - 4 bytes

Comment: @Pekka I already tried importing it back into my database with PHPMyAdmin, but it didn't help.

Comment: @Matiss: It's hard to follow exactly what you're seeing vs what you should see vs the raw bytes in the file. As I said before, if you could edit your question with the *exact* unicode character number, and the bytes used to represent it in the file, that would help.

Comment: @Matiss phpMyAdmin should offer you to specify the incoming file's encoding. What did you use there? Try playing around with the settings, i.e. switch between utf-8 and latin1. The only real problem would be if the two-byte `Å¡` would in itself consist of UTF-8 characters due to a botched double conversion - in that case, you'd have to convert to a single-byte encoding in your editor, and then import as utf-8. But I'm not sure that is the case here - try playing with the incoming character set setting first, if it's there. It's missing in some versions of phpMyAdmin

Comment: @Jon Please excuse Me, but I am quite the beginner and I do not know what is a Unicode character NUMBER, nor do I know how to find it. Could you please help me by explaining a little bit? I edited the question and added the bytes of a few characters.

Comment: @Jon and @Pekka I just tried encoding the .sql file to a lot of different charsets and suddenly I got the result I wanted. I feel terribly ashamed right now.. Well, thank you all for the help and for the new information you gave me, I really appreciated it!

Answer (score 0):

Encoding should be set on the connection on which you import data and read out data. If both of them are set to UTF-8, you will face no problems.

If you however import them with a latin1 connection, and later on reading it out with a UTF-8, you're in a world of trouble.

PHP internally only handles latin1, however that isn't nessecarily a problem for you.

If you have already wrongly imported the data, you would see a lot of ? or (diamond + ?) on your output I think.

But basically, when connecting frmo PHP, make sure to invoke `SET NAMES 'utf8'` first thing you do and see if that works.

If data still is wrong, you could use PHPs functions `utf8_encode / utf8_decode` to convert the data that is problematic.

In a working scenario they should never be used though.